# Android: get file names from directory in console

Tags: java, android, file

I want to `listFiles()` from the folder in Android but I got:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

This is how I try to print in the console:

```
final File assetsFolder = new File("src/main/assets");
printFiles(assetsFolder);

private void printFiles(final File folder){
        for(final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()){ //here is null
            if(fileEntry.isDirectory()){
                printFiles(fileEntry);
            } else {
                System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my project Structure:

```
Project
--ap
----src
------main
--------java
----------MainActivity <-- here I instantiate a class which is supposed to read files
--frameworkFolder
----src
------main
--------java <-- here is class with the code snippet I posted above
--------assets <- this is the folder which I want to read
```

How can I deal with the error? There are actually files in the folder. Why the compilator says its null?

Comment: Try file.exists(), before you try to work with it

Comment: You're right, I got false!

Answer (score 0):

Try get list file in asset folder

```
 AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
 String[] files = assetManager.list("");
```

Or try change

```
"src/main/asset"
```

to

```
"file:///android_asset/"
```

Comment: I will get assets from the app folder then, won't I? Not from the framework one